# Problem with logarithmic equation

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to solve the following equation and get an error in Mathematica.

```
Tfilter = 1/((L1*CC2)*(s^2 + (1/(RL*CC2))*s + 1/(L1*CC2)))
RL = 150;
L1 = 24.08 10^-3;
CC2 = 535.19 10^-9;
Tfilter
Eqn = 20 Log[10, Abs[Tfilter /. s -> I 2 \[Pi] f]] == -3 
FindRoot[Eqn, {f, 1}]
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> "FindRoot: Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point {f} = {1.}. Try perturbing the initial point(s)."

Can someone help me figure out what is wrong. I know the answer should be around 1400.

Thanks!

Comment: `FindRoot` needs a better starting value; use `FindRoot[Eqn, {f, 1000}]` or some other value closer to the expected value.

Comment: You could also use `NSolve[{Eqn // Rationalize[#, 0] &, f > 0}, f]`